# JQuery Reference for Popup Window

Tags: jquery

How to have JQuery reference for popu window?

I have JS below:

```
chatPage = window.open( ... );
chatPage.document.getElementById('someid');
```

I tried below but didn't work:

```
$(chatPage).$('#someid');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide `chatPage` as a context:

```
$('#someid', chatPage);
```

Comment: To show it, do I have to do it this way: `$('#someid', chatPage).show();`?